# Similar fonts to Segoe WP?

Tags: font-recommendation, font-licensing

I can't find anything about the Segoe WP licensing in Microsoft's website. So I was wondering if I could use it or no? Probably I can't and what I want to achieve is this:
[image: This is where the idea originates or Windows Phone itself.]
[image: This is a font that I found on the internet and here's how it looks on M$ Word]

I would appreciate it if you guys know about any similarities to this font!
And there are some big differences between Segoe UI and Segoe WP. The font I'm using on picture 2 is Segoe WP Semibold which I believe is also on picture 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Open Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans)

Open Sans is a very similar font to the Segoe family. It is a highly popular (and beautiful) font and you will find it wherever you go on the Web, even this StackExchange site.

[image: Open Sans sample]